# What's a good way to create space between images all while keeping it responsive?

Tags: html, css

How'd I go about making these images have space in between them all while keeping it responsive?  I've tried to use `padding`, `margin`, and I've also tried `font-size: 0;` because I saw it on SO - but to no avail.

I thought `display: inline-block;` would do the trick on the `banner-wrapper` class but that didn't do it either.

```css
.section-two-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.banner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid section-two-wrapper">
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/96/28/globe-icon-simple-minimal-96x96-pictograph-vector-19859628.jpg" class="l-logo" />
    <img src="https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/96/28/globe-icon-simple-minimal-96x96-pictograph-vector-19859628.jpg" class="play-store-logo" />
    <img src="https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/96/28/globe-icon-simple-minimal-96x96-pictograph-vector-19859628.jpg" class="app-store-logo" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Flexbox would be the way to go.

Comment: what is not responsive if you use `margin` or `padding`?

Comment: His `img`s are inline so he can not use those properties on the images. Images need to be set to `inline-block` first.

Comment: @Bouvanni yeah, basically I want to align these images in a row and have space in between them all while being responsive.  Do you mean I should add `display: inline-block;` on each image individually?

Comment: img have padding and margin by default without display set to inline-block . They are replaced elements. They are still display:inline by default but exhibit behaviour of inline-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my way to do it. Making the `banner-wrapper` to row-flexbox container, center the children. And the images have a size and margin dependent on the viewport-width

```css
.banner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
    
.banner-wrapper img {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  margin: 1vw 2vw;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid section-two-wrapper">
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/96/28/globe-icon-simple-minimal-96x96-pictograph-vector-19859628.jpg" class="lucktasitc-logo"/>
    <img src="https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/96/28/globe-icon-simple-minimal-96x96-pictograph-vector-19859628.jpg" class="play-store-logo"/>
    <img src="https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/96/28/globe-icon-simple-minimal-96x96-pictograph-vector-19859628.jpg" class="app-store-logo" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Got itttt thank you.  I understand this.  What if I wanted this to only affect desktop view and not mobile at all?

Comment: then wrap the specific css code in a media query, so that it only gets active if for example the screen has a specific minimum width

Answer (score 0):

Your images need to be block elements before you add margin or padding to them.
`img + img` chooses `img` elements which have a `img` directly before them so you don't apply margin to the first element.

An easier approach would be the flexbox.

```css
.banner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.banner-wrapper img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.banner-wrapper img + img {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* remove this if you want your elements to stay in one line */
}
```

```html
  <p>Using inline-block</p>
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/238x250" />
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/238x250" />
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/238x250" />
  </div>
  
   <p>Using flexbox</p>
  <div class="banner-wrapper flex">
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/238x250" />
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/238x250" />
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/238x250" />
  </div>
```